# Magento - how to setup countdown: Add $XX in cart and get free shipping

Tags: magento, cart, checkout

How do I add a countdown to a free shipping amount in Magento cart? I'm looking to add a small snippet of code by my cart on my Magento E-Commerce website, that will tell my customers how much more they will need to buy for to get free shipping.
For instance, I offer free shipping for all orders over $100, and the customer has added $60 worth of products to the cart - Then I would like to output 'Just add another $40 and GET FREE SHIPPING', and when we then reach the $100 benchmark, the echo will change to 'We will ship your order for free!'

Anyone out there that can figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Build an extension, get the cart value

```
$this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setSubtotalWithDiscount());
```

Add a config variable or something to check against and you have your value.

If you need help with it, there are a lot of people who can do it for you, me too. Invoice included :-)